# Hibernate SaveOrUpdate Error / Different error with merge

Tags: hibernate, merge, save

Hibernate Object:

Provider --> It has one to many relationship with ProviderAddress
and one to many relationship with ProviderStatusDetail

Earlier we were saving/updating the Provider Object to the database. Everything was working fine. Now we have to save the old values to a History table and then save/update the Provider Table.

Portions of the Code:

```
public void saveProvider(Provider provider) {

    //Get Existing Data from Provider
    Provider existingProvider = (Provider) this.getHibernateTemplate().get(Provider.class, provider.getProviderId());

    ProviderHistory providerHistory = null;
    providerHistory = new ProviderHistory();

    providerHistory.setProviderId(existingProvider.getProviderId());
    ...

    //Get Existing Data from Provider Status Detail
    ProviderStatusDetail existingProviderStatusDetail = (ProviderStatusDetail) this.getHibernateTemplate().get(ProviderStatusDetail.class,              

        existingProvider.getProviderStatusDetails().get(0).getProviderStatusDetailId());

    providerHistory.setTypeCode(existingProviderStatusDetail.getTypeCode());
    ...

    // Save Provider History Table
    this.getHibernateTemplate().save(providerHistory);

    // Get Existing Address Details
    Address address1 = this.getHibernateTemplate().get(Address.class,
                            existingProvider.getAddresses().get(0).getAddressId());

    // Save exsiting Practice Address to Address History Table
    ProviderAddressHistory practiceAdrHistory = null;
    adrHistory = new ProviderAddressHistory();

    adrHistory.setProviderId(provider.getProviderId());
    ...

    this.getHibernateTemplate().save(practiceAdrHistory);

    //Make some changes to the Status Detail Object
    for (ProviderStatusDetail psd : provider.getProviderStatusDetails()) {

            //Provider Type check
            if (psd.getTypeCode() != null 
                    && psd.getTypeCode() == 0) {
                psd.setTypeCode(null);
            }
    ...
    } 

    //Make sonme changes to Provider Object
    if (provider != null) {
            if (provider.getName() != null) {
                if (provider.getName().getPrefix() == 0) {
                    provider.getName().setPrefix(null);
                }
    }


    //Save Provider
    //this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(provider); //Error 1 - So commented this line

    //Save Provider with merge
    if (provider.getProviderId() > 0) {
            this.getHibernateTemplate().merge(provider); //Error 2
    } else {
            this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(provider);
    }
}
```

Error 1:
This line used to work fine before the History table changes. Now I get this error:

```
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.
```

Error 2:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging: com.abcd.ProviderStatusDetail
```

Can some one help me on this issue please. Hope my question is clear. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue using:

```
session.flush()
session.clear()
```

before the last saveOrUpdate(). Removed merge().